# JQuery MultiPage form.. validation on each step

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form which is split up into sections using pagination on each  tag. (See Fiddle)

I however have required fields in each section, I'd like to validate it so that fields with the "required" attribute must not be blank before the user moves on to the next section.

http://jsfiddle.net/Azxjt/

I've tried to following but don't think I'm on the right tracks:

```
 $(this).closest("article > :input").each(function() {

    if($(this).val == null) {

   con = 0;


    }

   });
    if ( con == 0 ) {
    alert("All fields must be filled in");
    }
    else {
    }
```

Your help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Text input will return a black value if no response has been entered.  Try the following

In jQuery, the value is returned by val()

```
$(this).val() == ""
```

You could possibly enhance your jQuery selector to test only those input elements with a corresponding required label.

Comment: I believe my selector doesn't actually select any elements which is half the battle :)

Comment: Try "article :input" instead of "article > :input" since you have div elements wrapping the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use `each` function.

```
var isEmpty;
$("input").each(function() {
   var element = $(this);
   if (element.val() == "") {
       isEmpty= true;
   }
});
```

Comment: This will return all inputs, I want to find all inputs in the current article